# Does Aspnet Core Authentication get triggered before Depedency Injection instantiates classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

With Aspnet Core, you can register classes for dependency injection

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IFoo, Foo>();
}
```

if you have a controller with authentication, does it still instantiate the controller before asserting whether the request is authenticated?

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IFoo _foo;

    public HomeController(
        IFoo foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }

    [HttpGet("bar")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok(_foo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication middleware triggers the challenge before the protected resource is loaded. Our development system uses the same log table for our Identity Server and the client application, so I added log entries to a constructor and the subsequent `HTTP GET` action and confirmed this (at least for ASP.NET Core 2.0 using OpenId Connect for authentication).

From my logs, which I blanked before hitting the protected resource, and I confirmed none of the preceding 93 log entries showed the constructor entry.

```
IS4    2018-02-23 14:07:25:4087598-05:00 Augmenting SignInContext
client 2018-02-23 14:07:26:8047778-05:00 *** CONSTRUCTOR ***
client 2018-02-23 14:07:26:8299852-05:00 *** GET INDEX ***
```